# Mongodb - $sort - Pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on aggregation in mongodb and am getting a "Pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field" from the below code

```
    db.HomeworkAggregate.aggregate([
    {
      $match:{
        number_of_employees:{
          $lte:500}},
          founded_year:{
            $gte:2000}},
          {$group: {
            _id: "$name"}, 
            description:"$description"},
            {$sort:{
              founded_year:1}}

])
```

I'm not sure what is causing it and have played with it for some time now, any help would be greatly appreicated, thank you.

Comment: Apart from the syntactical errors w.r.t pipeline stages (mostly braces for fields), that [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) would also not work as second field in that should be an accumulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your pipeline stage brackets in query

The correct arrangement should be

```
db.HomeworkAggregate.aggregate([
        {$match:{
            number_of_employees:{
                $lte: 500
            },
            founded_year:{
                $gte: 2000
            }
        }},
        {$group: {
            _id: "$name", 
            description: {$first: "$description"} // you can use other operators also
            founded_year: {$first: "$founded_year"}
        }},
        {$sort:{
            founded_year: 1
        }}
    ])
```

You are getting an error "Pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field" because there are some *unrecognized pipeline stages* because opening and closing brackets did not match.

Secondly, as you are sorting by "founded_year" **it should be added in $group stage** otherwise cursor result won't have a "founded_year" field, and will not sort with respect to "founded_year".

Also, you should use `$group accumulators` in the $group stage.

Please share if you are still facing any problems,